# Using the Office 365 navigation bar in website outside O365?

Tags: office365, office365api

Office 365 has a navigation bar at the top that follows the user across all services:

[image]

Is it possible to somehow use this outside of O365? For example, suppose I want to build a website that "feels" like it is a part of O365, but it is actually an external, completely self hosted site. I don't want to modify the suitebar, just have it present so the user feels familiar and can easily navigate back to other services in O365.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/javascript-controls, the AppChrome is very new and not so well documented. I have implemented this to my ASP.NET MVC webapp for O365.

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but faking the navigation bar is not an option for me.